# RichTextBox add some text in the middle of the text

Tags: c#, forms, richtextbox

I have a `RichTextBox` and I want to `add some text` in the `middle` of the `text`.
For example I got this text:

> "FirstText SecondText"

I want to add some text between the `"FirstText" and the "SecondText".`
I have tried to `split the text to 2 strings` and add to the first my extra text then add him the second string. It worked but it is destroy my richTextBox1.SelectionColor `(I got color...).`
So how can I add text without cutting my `richTextBox1.Text` or How can I save all the color data?

Comment: How are you setting the color?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the starting index yourself:

```
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(" ");
if (index > -1) {
  richTextBox1.Select(index, 1);
  richTextBox1.SelectedText = " Inserted Text ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the starting position and ending positions ? you could simply do something like this

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = index;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = length;//you need to assign an integer where to start
richTextBox1.SelectedText =  "Good";
```

it will replace whatever position in text where you have assigned length with the word "Good"

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850716/append-text-to-the-beginning-in-the-rich-text-box).

You might need to change the value of **SelectionStart** to the position where you want to put the new text.

In case you need to find the correct index, you can use something like this:

```
    startIndex = richTextBox1.Find(expressionToFind, 0,
                            richTextBox1.Text.Length,
                            RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
```

Hope it helps.